# css inner shadow with opacity 75% and 5px (the same as in psd)

Tags: html, css

I have a PSD file which has an element with an inner shadow.

The inner shadow effect has a blendmode of "multiply", the color is "black", the opacity is 75% and the size is 5px.

I have found out that I can make inner shadow in the following way:

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #000000;
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px #000000;
```

However, this doesn't take into account opacity 75%. Is there a way to set the opacity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add a opacity to your box-shadow you must use rgba. In your example you must do like this:

```
-moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow:         inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

The last number is opacity and first three are color (in this case Black).